# Redshift: Null Sort Key Stats in SVV_TABLE_INFO when SORTKEY AUTO is configured

Tags: amazon-redshift

I wanted to confirm if the following is true or if I am missing something: if a table in redshift is configured to have SORTKEY AUTO (assuming compound sortstyle, this style is default), then when we run a check on the meta data table SVV_TABLE_INFO for our table, that both the columns `unsorted` and `vacuum_sort_benefit` in that meta data table are null. Per [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html) `unsorted` indicates what percentage of the table is not sorted and `vacuum_sort_benefit` indicates the percentage of improvement we would received if we ran a vacuum. Thus, if both are null, my guess is that the optimization strategy determined (given the number of queries ran against the table and their predicates/complexities) that no sort key is needed. Anyone else see something similar or can confirm?

Comment: How large is the table in question? (in rows and in MBs) How many slices in your cluster?  If your table is too small there is no benefit that can be achieved

Comment: Looking at the largest table this is occurring on: 2.9M rows, 474 MB, and 65 slices.

Comment: That's fairly small for Redshift.  First a possible point of confusion - slices are a property of the Redshift cluster, 65 seems odd but not impossible; is this the column count of the table?  You see Redshift stores column data in 1MB blocks and each block stores about 250K rows (w/ lots of variability).  Rows are distributed around the slices so only a portion of the rows is in each slice.  If you have 8 slices only 375K rows on each slice which is only one block.  Sort keys help set the metadata for these blocks but since there is only one block, changing the sorting won't change anything.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at the wrong column in SVV_DISKUSAGE. There are 6 slices for the distkey column

Comment: no worries.  6 columns divides the rows 6 ways.  So about 500K rows per slice and between 1 and 2 blocks per slice depending on the column's data.  Still not a lot of differentiation in the block metadata.  I still think you don't have enough blocks in play for the Redshift AI to determine performance enhancing sortkeys.

Comment: Have you queried the table for a long table?
When the SORTKEY AUTO is used, Redshift will learn from your query patterns and modify the table accordingly for the best performance. However, you might not see the benefits until some hours have passed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Helena The table is queried a few times a day on a set number of queries for quite a while now. I get what you are saying though, that I should wait after executing the sortkey auto. I think in this context, the tables were set to be auto months ago.